# imagecreatefrompng() failed to open stream: HTTP request failed

Tags: php, image-processing, gd, imagecreatefrompng

On my local host this code works well:

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng('BBcode.png');
```

But when I use the same code in the server

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng('http://lazertag.elitno.net/drupal/BBcode.png');
```

I got the folloowing error:

> Warning:
>   imagecreatefrompng(http://lazertag.elitno.net/drupal/BBcode.png)
>   [function.imagecreatefrompng]: failed to open stream: HTTP request
>   failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in
>   /www/elitno.net/l/a/lazertag/home/site/drupal/renderImage.php on line
>   46

How do I solve this?

Comment: `HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden` is pretty clear, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is on your server, use a (relative) system path, not an url:
E.g.:

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng('drupal/BBcode.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

Before using imagecreate, can you download remote image into a local folder then work on it ?!

your ex:

```
$imagefile = file_get_contents('http://lazertag.elitno.net/drupal/BBcode.png');
$fp  = fopen('./BBcode.png', 'w+'));
fputs($fp, $imagefile);
fclo$fp);
unset($imagefile);
$im = imagecreatefrompng('./BBcode.png');
```

Comment: you have missing letters in the `fclose(...)` line

Comment: It's my server and the file i want to use is already stored on my server.

Comment: @alexey then find out why it's returning a 403 and fix it (or use a file path as suggested by @scessor)

Answer (score 0):

403 Forbidden means that the server blocked you from accessing the file. you can try doing a file_get_contents("http://...."); do get an error message, maybe the creator's of the site put one in place else you have to talk to them.