# "imagecreatefrompng" Not working on server but in localhost

Tags: php, captcha

I used `imagecreatefrompng` function to generate captcha. It works fine in localhost and not in web server
this is my code

```
$captcha_base_img = base_url("assets/images/captcha_back.png");
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($captcha_base_img); 
//returns an image identifier representing a black image of the specified size(w,h)
```

php info

> gd GD Support enabled GD Version  bundled (2.1.0 compatible) FreeType
>   Support   enabled FreeType Linkage    with freetype FreeType Version  2.3.11
>   GIF Read Support  enabled GIF Create Support  enabled JPEG
>   Support   enabled libJPEG Version 6b PNG Support  enabled libPNG
>   Version   1.2.49 WBMP Support enabled XBM Support enabled

what would be the reason?

```
$image returns false;
```

it is a png image

error log :

> Warning --> imagecreatefrompng(http://url/captcha_back.png) [function.imagecreatefrompng]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Comment: is it the exact same image you tested with in localhost? Is it definitely there on the server in the correct location? And are you not getting an exception or warning as well as the "false" return value?

Comment: what does your [**PHP error log**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel) tell you?

Comment: @Martin error log Warning --> imagecreatefrompng(http://landreclamation.lk/demo_apps/assets/images/captcha_back.png) [<a href='function.imagecreatefrompng'>function.imagecreatefrompng</a>]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Comment: So that clearly shows you the issue: your image is not there or you have access issues in reaching the image

Comment: See also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454695/imagecreatefrompng-failed-to-open-stream-http-request-failed

Comment: Samm; if your image is on your local server then you **don't** need to do a remote call, but instead should be doing a `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` call to the file location.

Comment: In my case, I got warnings messages in other lines which affects the functionality of  the creating image.